# LUA Variables at the end of syntax?

Tags: lua, roblox

my code below when fired fires multiple times but without the variable attached its blank on the end how do i make it fire with the variable added?

game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")["Code_Folder"]   <-Blank Var

```
local children = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")["Code_Folder"]:GetChildren() --Set Folder
for i, child in ipairs(children) do --Get Children of Folder
print(child) --Print the Children of Code_Folder
local A_1 = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")["Code_Folder"],child <-???????????????  <-- How to append Varialbe onto A_1
local Event = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").EnterCode <-- Then Fire A-1 with each variable
Event:FireServer(A_1)
end
```

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking. Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, what is `game`? What do you mean by "adding the variable"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to fire a RemoteEvent and pass parameters to the Server.

```
-- in a LocalScript, fire the event
local rs = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local event = rs.Code_Folder.EnterCode
event:FireServer("valueA", "valueB", "valueC")
```

Then in a server Script, listen for the event. The first parameter will be the player that fired the event, and all the other values will come after it :

```
-- observe the event
local rs = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local event = rs.Code_Folder.EnterCode
event.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, val1, val2, val3)
    print(player.Name, val1, val2, val3)
end)
```